# Wait until method has finished to call the method again

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a method which "does stuff" do my `ListView` called `method1()`.  This is called from `method2()`.  `method2()` can run very frequently (possibly every second). I think I have a problem that if `method2()` is called (therefore calling `method1()` again) before `method1()` has finished, `method1` only runs the once - it does not run the second time.

Is there a way around this? I thought about adding a `boolean` into `method1()` and setting it to `true` at the start and the `false` at the end, but I can't think of a way I can get this to work.

**EDIT:**

I did some more testing and the method was being called serially so the question is obsolete. I apologize for this.

Comment: Are you multithreading? This should never happen as on a single thread, execution proceeds *serially*.

Comment: @hexafraction I am not in this scenario. `method2()` is called from a broadcast receiver though. The broadcast receiver is "created" multiple times by using a different request code.

Answer (score 1):

Make the function synchronized:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

this will ensure that in a multithreaded environment only one thread can access the function simultanious.

Comment: So I just add `synchronized` to the method and that is it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. But be aware that calling a `synchronized` method is more CPU consuming than calling a normal method.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use TimerTask

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if(!isRunning)
                {
                    // Repeat You can update UI using runOnUiThread(runnable)
                }
                if(jobDone)
                {
                    this.cancel();

                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(tt, 0, 1);
```

just a trick

Comment: Am I supposed to put something in the "repeat" part, or does it repeat automatically?

Comment: yes it repeat every 1 sec and check if you want to run your method if not running say set isRunning = true  at start of method and at end set isRunning = false in loop it check if isRunning do nothing if !isRunning  then again repeat you method if any time you want to quit just set jobDone = true it just quite

Comment: This does not work for me because I cannot modify the ui from another thread. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: OK, I can still use the ui thread, but I don't think I want to use the timer as it is constantly checking every second. I had a similar implementation using a handler, but it just slowed every thing down so I was trying to avoid using this sort of thing

Answer (score -2):

Give method 1 a public static Boolean and set it to false. This can be called "Done" if you'd like.
When method 1 is done, set that variable to true.

Method 2 can run a while loop before the method1 call.

while( method1.done == false ) {

}
method1

Comment: Even in the rare case where a spinn lock would be appropriate, this implementation is not thread safe.